# Parameter 'event' value is not used

Tags: python, user-interface, button

I'm developing a program in python 2.7 and have run into an issue on Pycharm. In the program, I want the user to be able to navigate through different screens by either clicking buttons, or by pressing the "enter" key. I tried implementing it into my program, and it works but Pycharm is giving the error

[image: Parameter 'event' is not used]

```
    import Tkinter as Tk


    class MemoryGameApp(Tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            Tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            Tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "2 screens")
            container = Tk.Frame(self)
            container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.frames = {}
            for F in (StartPage, PageTwo):
                frame = F(container, self)
                self.frames[F] = frame
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.show_frame(StartPage)

            def show_frame(self, cont):
                frame = self.frames[cont]
                frame.tkraise()

    class StartPage(Tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
                label = Tk.Label(self, text="Page 1")
                label.pack()
                global button
                button = Tk.Button(self, text="Next", width=5, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
                button.pack(pady=100, padx=100)
                button.focus_set()

                def press_enter(event):
                    controller.show_frame(PageTwo)
                    button2.focus_set()

                button.bind("<Return>", press_enter)

    class PageTwo(Tk.Frame):
            def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
                label_title2 = Tk.Label(self, text="Page 2")
                label_title2.pack()
                global button2
                button2 = Tk.Button(self, text="Back", width=5, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
                button2.pack(pady=100, padx=100)

                def press_enter(event):
                    controller.show_frame(StartPage)
                    button.focus_set()

                button2.bind("<Return>", press_enter)

    app = MemoryGameApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

It has given the error in def press_enter(event):

It claims that event is not used, but if I remove it from the program, the program does not function correctly

I know that it works when it is implemented, I'm just interested in seeing if there's anyway that I can remove this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Fix your indentation. This code is unreadable and cannot be interpreted.

Comment: No problems. Indentation has been fixed.

Comment: This isn't an error. This is just a hint your IDE gives you. This variable isn't used anywhere, indeed, so it thinks that it might not be needed. However, it doesn't mean there's something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 10):

To remove this warning, you could replace the argument 'event' by '_', or just do something with the object, like printing it to console.

Even though the argument of the function seems useless, it cannot be removed: It belongs to the signature of a valid event function.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to change *event* to *_event*.

Comment: I find this answer better in case of an update of the function